# rails 3 ActionView::Template::Error (no block given (yield))

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views, yield, actionview

This code was working in rails 2.3.X...but it return this error in rails 3.0.9

```
ActionView::Template::Error (no block given (yield)):
7:            <%= yield %>
app/views/colones/_colone.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_colones__colone_html_erb__407265174181794185_76812160_3109567765965463980'
```

It work if i call yield from layout or by with a locals (partial) like that

```
<%= render :partial => 'colones/colone', :locals => { :colone => @colones.first } %>
```

but if failed when I try :

```
<%= render @colones %>
```

or

```
<%= render :partial => 'colones/colone', :collection => @colones %>
```

If should have another way to accomplish that because the only thing I found to work around is very ugly:

```
<%= render :partial => 'colones/colone', :locals => { :colone => @colones.first %>
<%= render :partial => 'colones/colone', :locals => { :colone => @colones.second %>
```

I think it's a part of this problem but I'm not 100% sure ... I'll try to pass a collection

Someone have any suggestion or explaination on how to solve this ERROR?

thank you

Comment: can we see app/views/colones/_colone.html.erb because I don't know what you are trying to yield.

Comment: okay... so what are you intending to yield... what should it do.

Comment: It should yield render the html action pages of my controller index.html.erb

Comment: I think the content it should return does'nt matter...I got the same results even if the action page is empty.

Comment: I know that yield expects a block or a symbol that is used with content_for.  Is that want you want? to render something expressed in the index.html.erb template?

Comment: I understood what you are trying to said but even with yield(:exemple) it still raised the same error